# !isdigit isnt working (C programming)

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a random number guessing game that generates a random number between 1-10 and have the user guess it. It then tells the user if they're right or not. That part works fine, but the problem also asked for me to utilize the isdigit() function. I cannot get this to work for some reason. It says everything is a digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    int x;
    int r;

    r=(rand() %10)+1;
    r=6;
    printf(" Select a number between 1 and 10 \n");
    scanf(" %d", &x);

    if(!isdigit(x)){
        if(x==r)
            printf("Congratulations, you guessed correctly! \n");


    else{
        printf("Uh oh! You guessed the wrong number! \n");
        printf("The correct guess was %d \n",r);
}


    }
    else{
        printf("That is not a number! \n");

}
}
```

Comment: Post the code, not a picture of it

Comment: Please put as little effort as copy-pasting your code and formatting it as code. Don't post screenshots of your code.

Comment: sorry, new to the site, i edited the post witht he code pasted in

Comment: `isdigit()` checks whether a character represents a digit (looks for eg. numbers corresponding to ASCII codes for '0' through '9', or whatever's appropriate for the character set in use), not whether an `int` represents a number (which it generally always would).

Comment: Also, if `isdigit()` *did* check whether a number was entered, your logic would still be backwards (checking for a correct guess only when a number was *not* entered).

Comment: okay, so one more thing. It now says that the answer is always wrong even if the right answer has been entered. I apologize for being annoying lol i'm super new to programming.

Comment: I can't see the relevance of using `isdigit` unless the input was `int x = getchar()` but since the input can be 0 to 10 I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Is digit expects an ascii character - with '0','1','2','3' ... being values that will return non zero.

Your code is getting the actual value input (as an example 104 which would have been ascii values '1' '0' '4') and setting x to the converted integer value and then seeing if that is a ascii digit value.

You probably want to use the return code of scanf to determine whether it read a numeric value.

If, you were going to use isdigit, you would need to read the value as a string, then use isdigit on each character in the string to verify the are numbers. And then convert the string to a number using sscanf, or atoi.